How can I calculate the scaling exponent for a Pareto distribution?
I can see that a random variable $X$ with Pareto type IV distribution has density
$$f_{X}(x; k,\alpha,\gamma,\mu) = \frac{\alpha  k^{-1/\gamma } (x-\mu )^{\frac{1}{\gamma }-1} \left(\left(\frac{k}{x-\mu }\right)^{-1/\gamma }+1\right)^{-\alpha -1}}{\gamma }$$
using for example:
$$\text{PDF}[\text{ParetoDistribution}[k,\alpha ,\gamma ,\mu ],x]$$
in Mathematica 14.0.
The density looks like a straight line on a log-log plot. What's the gradient? This is sometimes called the scaling exponent.

Does looking at the gradient of the doubly logarithmic plot and expanding about the parameters work?...some calculation:
The difficulty is that the derivative I need is not obviously zero without some manipulations, and the range of the parameters introduce some complex numbers if not dealt with properly. If I change variable using $X = \log(x)$ and $Y = \log(y)$, then
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}Y}{\mathrm{d}X} = \frac{(\alpha +1) e^X}{\gamma  \left(e^X-\mu \right) \left(\left(\frac{k}{\mu - e^X}\right)^{1/\gamma }+1\right)}$$
and this should be independent of $X$, giving a flat line intercepting the $Y$ axis at the desired scaling exponent. This indeed seems to be the case for various choices of the parameters. But can you write this scaling exponent in terms of the parameters? A zeroth-order series expansion at $x=\mu$ suggests
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}Y}{\mathrm{d}X} = \frac{(\alpha +1) e^{\mu }}{\gamma  \left(\mu-e^{\mu } \right) \left(\left(\frac{k}{e^{\mu }-\mu }\right)^{1/\gamma }+1\right)}$$
assuming $x \approx \log(\mu)$, which for unit parameters appears to give an exponent of $-2$, so this is a tentative answer. But is this the simplest expression? And do we need a series expansion around a parameter value to get an expression for the exponent?

According to Wikipedia, that is the survival function $(1-CDF)$ rather than the density

For $x\ge \mu$.

edited, I can get the PDF.
